# Auto start my own scripts in Windows Server

Tags: windows, powershell

The several clients use scanners and send .tiff files into shared folder. This scanners can't transfer those result to pdf. How can I start my script for automatically transfer this .tiff files to .pdf? Which variants I have in the Windows Server 2012? Better if this script will work after each time after create new .tiff file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Watch out for `FileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: I'm finding out how I can solve this problem. I didn't understand how processes work into the Windows Server. I have experience only in Linux...

Comment: [Monitoring Folders for File Changes](https://powershell.one/tricks/filesystem/filesystemwatcher)

Comment: You can use FileSystemWatcher to monitor and the free Imagick https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows to do the conversion, t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To monitor for file changes in the server directory

StartMonitoring.ps1

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "D:\source"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                Add-content "D:\log.txt" -value $logline
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

How to use

```
Create a new text file
Copy & paste the above code
Change the following settings to your own needs:
    folder to monitor: $watcher.Path = "D:\source"
    file filter to include only certain file types: $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    include subdirectories yes/no: $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
Save and rename it to StartMonitoring.ps1
Start monitoring by Right click » Execute with PowerShell
```

To stop monitoring, it's enough to close your PowerShell window

to convert from .tiff to PDF try:

```
$InputLocation = "C:\convert"

$tool = 'C:Program Files (x86)\PDFCreator\PDFCreator.exe'
$tiffs = get-childitem  -filter *.tif -path $InputLocation

foreach($tiff in $tiffs)
{
    $filename = $tiff.FullName
    $pdf = $tiff.FullName.split('.')[0] + '.pdf'


    'Processing ' + $filename  + ' to ' + $pdf      
    $param = "-sOutputFile=$pdf"
    Start-Process $tool -ArgumentList ('/IF"' + $filename + '" /OF"' + $pdf + '/NoPSCheck /NoStart')
}
```